# How to fix the white line added by CSS transform on hover?

Tags: css, hover, line, transform, scale

Did someone found or knows a working fix for the white line/border that appears on an element that is transformed with CSS scale on hover?

I tried things like: `transform: translateZ(0)`, `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`, `transform-style: preserve-3d` and nothing helped.

This bug can be seen very well on a **non-retina** display.

[Here is a video](https://www.screenmailer.com/v/96E5qEjYuGaZnOk) for those who can't see the bug, you will note an 1px like line at the bottom of the image.

```css
section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(43, 43, 54, 0.3);
  transition: background 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.2, 1);
}

.ct-image-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.2, 1);
}

.ct-image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}

article:hover figure:before {
  background: rgba(43, 43, 54, 0.7);
}

article:hover .ct-image-container {
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478033394151-c931d5a4bdd6?w=1568&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465126188505-4f04a0f23a4d?w=1550&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495250357898-6822052ef5b8?w=1650&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446080501695-8e929f879f2b?w=1567&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>

        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506512534708-3737d46bffe1?w=1650&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="ct-card-inner">
            <figure>
              <a href="" class="ct-image-container">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503924087716-07cbd5f49b21?w=1000&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
                <div class="ct-ratio" style="padding-bottom: 133.3%"></div>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CreativeDreams/Lsf1q4gt/3/)

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please include the code inside your Post.

Comment: @TomM just added the code.

Comment: In which browsers the problem appears?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn sorry, I forgot to mention. This problem seems to be only in Chrome. I tested this in Chrome 62.0.3202.62 and Chrome Canary 64.0.3248.0

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` to your img tag seems to fix this.

I will use this approach instead:

Be sure to comment out the CSS below

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    /* object-fit: cover; */
    /* object-position: center center; */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Should fix it!